# Get value from xml/json file in vb.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, vb.net, jsonobjectrequest

I am using `Vb.net` and I have written following code to get `data` using `json object deserialization`.

`abc` is a string format and the value is:

```
 { 
    "state":"success",
     "data"
          {
            "height":200,
            "width":0 
           }
 }


jsonObject = JsonConvert.DesirializeObject(Of xyz)(abc)
```

Now, I need to get the values of `height and/or width` based on the condition when the state is successful.

Please help me how can I get the values from inside data.

I tried for status as below:

```
jsonObject.state = "status"
```

But I don't know what to use for `data` and getting `height and width`.

Comment: Since you're deserializing into a defined class type, you should be able to use `jsonObject.data.height` and `jsonObject.data.width`.  What happens if you try to do that?

Comment: If you could post the structure of your 'xyz' class, the community might be able to provide more assistance.  It's difficult to guess what your class might look like - you might be missing a sub-class or property that is not providing what you need to access the properties you want when the object gets de-serialized.